# Graphically solving a Linear Programming Problem?

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions, linear-programming, operations-research

I was given the following linear programming problem and have been asked to find all optimal solutions graphically. I am quite new to the subject, so please forgive my naivety.

$$\min\quad z = x - y$$
$$\text{subject to: }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$x + y \le 6$$
$$x - y \ge 0$$
$$y - x \ge 3$$
$$x, y \ge 0$$

I've graphed the constraints as shown below:
[image]

To me, it seems like there are no optimal solutions because there is no feasible region (that is, a region where all constraints are satisfied and therefore all three shaded colors would overlap). Is my assumption correct or is there an optimal solution(s) to this problem, and how could I go about finding it (them) graphically?

Comment: If you add the two constraints $x-y\geq0$ and $y-x\geq 3$, you get $0\geq 3$, which cannot be. So, indeed, either the constraint set is empty and thus there is no solution, or there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: True, I never thought about that. But I'm pretty sure there are no typos here, so there must be no solution.

Comment: Please make your answer an answer to the question so I may properly give you credit.

Comment: @audiFanatic may I know how have you plotted such a colorful and accurate graph, any software or website?

Comment: Whatever you have done is correct.

Comment: I used a freeware program plainly called "Graph." Very simple and easy to use: http://www.padowan.dk/download/

Comment: See the link in my previous comment to download it

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your observation as there exists no optimal solutions. Here is what the following model looks like in Desmos:

[image: Desmos image of a Linear Programming Model]

From here, we can observe that the constraints $y-x\ge3$ and $x-y\ge0$ conflict with one another in such a way that they do not overlap. Thus, there will never exist a point that will concurrently satisfy all three constraints.

---

Suppose we are not satisfied with the graphical representation with the model, or we did not consider a graphical approach, and we wanted to proceed via the Simplex method. Thus, using the Big-M approach we would standardize our model as such:

$$\min z -x+y-M(a_2+a_3)$$
Subject to,
$$x+y+s_1=6$$
$$x-y-e_2+a_2=0$$
$$y-x-e_3+a_3=3$$
$$x,y,e_2,e_3,a_2,a_3\ge0$$

Where $M$ is the "largest" number in $\Bbb R$.

Our initial tableau setup would look like:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x & y & e_2 & e_3 & s_1 & a_2 & a_3 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -M & -M & 0 & - \\
\hline s_1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & - \\
 ? & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & - \\
 ? & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & - \\
\hline 
\end{array}

After solving for our missing basic variables:
\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x & y & e_2 & e_3 & s_1 & a_2 & a_3 & RHS & RT \\
\hline   z & 1 & -1 &  1 & -M & -M & 0 &  0 & 0 & 3M & - \\
\hline s_1 & 0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 & 1 &  0 & 0 & 6 & 6 \\
       a_2 & 0 &  1 & -1 & -1 &  0 & 0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & \infty \\
       a_3 & 0 & -1 &  1 &  0 & -1 & 0 &  0 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline 
\end{array}

From here, would pivot the $y$ column with the $a_3$ row (for this we are assuming $\frac{0}{-\delta}=-0=\infty$ to follow the traditional pivoting rule of ignoring negative numbers in the minimum-ratio-test) to get the following tableau:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x & y & e_2 & e_3 & s_1 & a_2 & a_3 & RHS & RT \\
\hline   z & 1 &  0 &  0 & -M & -M+1 & 0 &  0 & -1 & 3M -3 & - \\
\hline s_1 & 0 &  2 &  0 &  0 &  1   & 1 &  0 & -1 & 3  & - \\
       a_2 & 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1   & 0 &  1 &  1 & 3  & - \\
         y & 0 & -1 &  1 &  0 & -1   & 0 &  0 &  1 & 3  & - \\
\hline 
\end{array}

Notice that we are unable to pivot anymore and $a_2$ is still a basic variables such that our right-hand-side of our objective function is $3M-3$. Thus, this model is infeasible.

Graphically where this basis is located in the model can be shown in the red circle within the following image:

[image]

However, notice that there exists another point that shares the same objective function value as this point, as the reduced-cost-coefficient of $x$ is zero and $x=0$ since it is a non-basic variable. We'll leave that to the reader to figure out where that point is.